# How to find points within Polygon?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search, hibernate-spatial

I recently work with hibernate spatial and I have such a question. I wanna to get all points inside polygon. How can I do that?

For example my distance query looks lite this:

```
    final Coordinates coordinates = Point.fromDegrees(searchDistanceParameters.getLatitude(), searchDistanceParameters.getLongitude());
    final Query fromCoordinates = SpatialQueryBuilderFromCoordinates.buildDistanceQuery(coordinates, searchDistanceParameters.getDistance(), "location");
    final FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    final FullTextQuery textQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(fromCoordinates, GeoPointModel.class);
```

I create a Polygon like this:

```
        GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
        Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(coordinates);
```

But what can I use to get points inside this polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Search 5's spatial support only covers distance queries. Matching points inside a polygon is not supported.

Hibernate Search 6 does provide [a "within polygon" predicate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-spatial-within), but APIs in Hibernate Search 6 are different from those in Search 5.
If you're fine with that, you can use the latest Beta: http://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/ . You might want to have a look at the [getting started guide for Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started) first, so as to understand the new APIs before you migrate.

If you need to stay on Hibernate Search 5, you will have to use `lucene-spatial`: implement bridges to index points as `lucene-spatial` expects, and  generate lucene-spatial queries directly with lucene-spatial APIs.